# The Combination of Field Recordings and Music

Tags: field, recording, music, composition

I'd like to start a list of examples of this particular combination, so please post any you can think of or any other thoughts about this.

Here's one I think really works:

[youtube]VVuJ_E_q4LI[/youtube]

[Brokeback - The Wilson Ave Bridge by the Chicago River 1953](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVuJ_E_q4LI)

Comment: i have this on vinyl. nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever seen any of Diego Stocco's work? It's really amazing what he does. Here's an example

[Diego Stocco - Music from Nature](http://vimeo.com/43198585) from [Diego Stocco](http://vimeo.com/diegostocco) on [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com).

But check out all his other videos which are fantastic and really creative.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've encountered his work before - always very inspirational. Thinking about this question again, I think I'm more interested in recordings and music together rather than composition from field recordings (though the lines can get blurry, I know).

Comment: was about to ask that question and yes lines are blurry. i'll see what i can find.

Comment: Oh ok... Maybe check out the John Mayer/Frank Ocean track on the new John Mayer album which has an ambience field recording throughout... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6z7c-nIQ6M



Answer (score 1):

Hi,

Some examples:

Aphex Twin - On
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-US91WU8zA

Max Richter - Memory House
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Bb0k9HgQxc

Almost anything by 'Boards of Canada' especially on "The campfire headphase"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dhwx67X-0eE

Arovane - 'Lilies' and 'Tides' albums
Passage to Nagoya
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwWtsUr5hWM

Bibio: several albums

Ambivalence Avenue 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgGsnYpT3zg

And there's lots more..

Answer (score 1):

so it sounds like you are looking for music that combines more traditional field recordings, ambience recordings as opposed to found sound and foley type recordings being used as rhythmic components in music.

off the top of my head i'd add:

[Jon Hopkins - Autumn Hill](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9_jzBtdMZ4)

[Jon Hopkins - Small Memory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6i5x1rwGYw)

[Richard Skelton - Pariah](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jh-HNJWlkMw)

and basically his whole album Landings

[Undertow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KF4Fy1_whyk)

Mountains, the album "Sewn" but you seem to be hip to Thrill Jockey already

[Lusine lcl - A Day Apart](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fQSWxTh35k)

If you go to www.othermusic.com and browse the "OUT" section you will find tons of this kind of stuff.

Also, here's an example of this that I have done.

[echo conscious - without sinking](https://soundcloud.com/echoconscious/without-sinking)

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I'm more interested in straight recordings and music  - how the two interact. Thanks for the suggestions. Really like that Lusine track, I'll definitely seek the albumn out.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw this question, I immediately thought of some of the ambient music I've listened to.

"Chill Out," by The KLF is full of them, along with samples of Elvis, Tuvan throat singing, and an insane salesman. http://youtu.be/C5TUEv1wf-c

At least one track from Brian Eno's "Ambient 4: On Land" fits this, too. I don't have it at the moment, though, so I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Thanks, I've not listened to the KLF for a while! Love the trains... 

Answer (score 1):

Hi,

You should take a look at Amon Tobin's album 'Foley Room'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mhxw-pqB4VU
And his others albums are great pieces of sound design too !

Hope you'll enjoy !